# I can not fix an incorrect location for chrome: is there a way to manually enter my location?

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, google-maps

I have gone through various Q&A on allowing `chrome` to detect my location. Here are the instructions from `google search`

[image]

```
Click Settings and then At the bottom, click Advanced.
In the "Privacy and security" section, click Content settings.
Click "Location" and then make sure that Ask before accessing (recommended) is turned on.
```

These steps have been followed and in fact the following had already been set:

> click "Location" and then make sure that Ask before accessing (recommended) is turned on.

[image]

But location refuses to work

[image]

Can I simply enter my current location and have chrome "believe" me about it?

Comment: Did you allow it under macOS System Preferences - Security - Privacy - Location Services? Also WiFi is required.

Comment: @JamesBrickley That seems to have been unchecked for `chrome` . Feel free (/encouraged) to make it an answer